# How to keep selected item in dropdown list in php?

Tags: php

I am using this code to switch language in my website. Everything works fine but when I change language always first item is selected. I want to keep selected which language is website language. Here is my code.

```
<td width="85%" align=right class=top_section> 
          <form method='POST'>
          <select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
          <option value="en" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected';?>English</option> 
          <option value="ru" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'ru') echo 'selected';?>Русский</option> 
          <option value="tj" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'tj') echo 'selected';?>Точики</option> 
          </select> 

    </form>
    </td>
```

How to make it work properly? If russian language is selected it should stay in russian. But it always goes to English.

And using this code to change website language

```
if(!isset($_POST['switchlanguage']))
  {
  include_once($DOCUMENT_LANG.'en.lng.php');
  }
  else
  {
  include_once($DOCUMENT_LANG.$_POST['switchlanguage'].'.lng.php');
  }
```

Even when I use tab to enter dropdownbox and using down key, it is automatically goes to first item.

Comment: You should put language in session and then check session instead of `$_POST` to define the selected item.

Comment: How to do that? Can you give me some code please?

Comment: i think instead of echo 'selected' you need to use echo 'selected="selected"'

Comment: I used 'selected="selected"'   It did not work...

Comment: as I don't know PHP what does this line `include_once($DOCUMENT_LANG.$_POST['switchlanguage'].'.lng.php');` do and you should try `if(!isset($_POST['switchlanguage']))
  {
  $_POST['switchlanguage'] ='ru';
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I did not know that for smarty we need <{php}> and <{/php}> tags.
So writing  was not been known by smarty. I wrote finally this code and it worked.

```
<form method='POST'>
      <select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
      <option value="en" <{php}>if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected="selected"';<{/php}>> English</option> 
      <option value="ru" <{php}>if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'ru') echo 'selected="selected"';<{/php}>> Русский</option> 
      <option value="tj" <{php}>if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'tj') echo 'selected="selected"';<{/php}>> То?ик?</option> 
      </select>
```

Thanks for everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, how about using cookies? I think that should be fairly SOP for this problem, unless you can't use them for some reason (i.e. you don't want to care with the EU laws regarding cookies?)

Answer (score 0):

You Should use

```
selected="selected"
```

not a PHP programmer but can you try

```
<td width="85%" align=right class=top_section> 
          <form method='POST'>
          <select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
          <option value="en" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected="selected"';?>English</option> 
          <option value="ru" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'ru') echo 'selected="selected"';?>Русский</option> 
          <option value="tj" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'tj') echo 'selected="selected"';?>Точики</option> 
          </select> 

    </form>
    </td>
```

Hey just try

```
<form method='POST'>
          <select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
          <option value="en" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected="selected"';?>> English</option> 
          <option value="ru" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'ru') echo 'selected="selected"';?>> Русский</option> 
          <option value="tj" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'tj') echo 'selected="selected"';?>> Точики</option> 
          </select> 

    </form>
```

Comment: No it did not work, Now it always stays in 3rd item. Which is tj.

Comment: @vikas For your information "selected" is a naked attribute allowed by HTML4 and HTML5
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

selected="selected" is necessary only if you go for a XHTML strict DTD.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov I am not PHP guy, so just check the edited code after Hey just try

Comment: @vikas No even 'Hey just try' did not work, it always jumps to first item.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov can you check `$_POST['switchlanguage']` value in `alert($_POST['switchlanguage'])`;

Answer (score 0):

You have some typo in your code.
See this

```
<option value="en" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected';?>English</option>
```

this should be

```
<option value="en" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected'; ?>>English</option>
```

Note the closing brace of option start tag(before English and other languages).

You may just replace your select code with this one:

```
<select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
    <option value="en" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected'; ?>>English</option> 
    <option value="ru" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'ru') echo 'selected'; ?>>Русский</option> 
    <option value="tj" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'tj') echo 'selected'; ?>>Точики</option> 
</select>
```

**EDIT:**

Does your edit code looks like this,

```
<?php
$_POST['switchlanguage'] ='ru';
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="85%" align=right class=top_section> 
        <form method='POST'>
            <select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
                <option value="en" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected'; ?>>English</option> 
                <option value="ru" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'ru') echo 'selected'; ?>>Русский</option> 
                <option value="tj" <?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'tj') echo 'selected'; ?>>Точики</option> 
            </select> 
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tested this at my end and its working fine.

Comment: If I put your code in my dropdown listbox showing >English >Russian >Tajik   Even with this it is not working.

Comment: Yes it is. Like this >English

Comment: put `<?php $_POST['switchlanguage'] ='ru'; ?>` before your dropdown code

Comment: What you mean? Inside <option> or outside <option>?

Comment: Before `<select name="switchlanguage`

Comment: can you post your modified code here. I mean append that to your question.

Comment: This should surely work if it is not working then I guess the problem is something else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24106/discussion-between-firdavs-kurbonov-and-ravi)

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you can use one or more of the following:

- anonymous user choose the language: go for a PHP script that sets a cookie with the value of the lang selected, e.g. setcookie("switchlanguage", 'en', time()+3600, "/", "example.com");
- authenticated user: you may think to store the preferred language of the current user in you DB (then make a script that stores and retrieves the selection)
- u can always think of using session to store the lang but it will expire when user leaves your website(starts a new session)

In any of the above cases you'll need to make a script that sets the lang val in a Cookie, Session or DB and then redirects back to the original page. Or better make a Ajax call to this PHP script that stores the val and then return a JSON object with the value set or an error.

Finally u'll need to adjust your HTML to select the correct language (ex. with cookies):

```
<select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
<option value="en" <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['switchlanguage']) || empty($_COOKIE['switchlanguage']) || $_COOKIE['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected';?>English</option> 
<option value="ru" <?php if($_COOKIE['switchlanguage'] == 'ru') echo 'selected';?>Русский</option> 
<option value="tj" <?php if($_COOKIE['switchlanguage'] == 'tj') echo 'selected';?>Точики</option> 
</select>
```

I added also the default case u were missing :
(!isset($_COOKIE['switchlanguage']) || empty($_COOKIE['switchlanguage']) )
when no lang is still selected choose english.

Comment: Can I do it with $_POST or should I use $_COOKIE?

Comment: If you store the lang in a cookie you then need to use $_COOKIE superglobal array to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

is this post result

```
<?php if($_POST['switchlanguage'] == 'en') echo 'selected="selected"';?. ?>
```

coming from some other page or are you changing lanuage on this page itself .If it is coming from some other page through a post request then its ok but if you are changing your language on this page itself , use javascript to get particular field selected.

Comment: I am changing language of whole website. Language dropdown only in index.php

Comment: then you have to get the post value before submitting the form.

Comment: ok think clearly, first time you call form.submit, is $_POST['switch_language'] value is there ?

Comment: yes it is, because my website language is changed... The problem is only in dropdownbox...When I choose Russian it loads russian language pack, but shows English in dropdownlist box.

Comment: yeah that may be the case.. re write using some other logic like create a variable and using conditions assign "selected = 'selected'" to it and echo in your options.

Answer (score 0):

As I could not find better solution, I did a little trick... I added one more option. It will always go to 1st option. First option is Choose language. If somebody finds another approach I will be happy. For now I could not find better solution.

```
<td width="85%" align=right class=top_section> 
    <form method='POST'>
          <select name="switchlanguage" onchange="this.form.submit()"> 
          <option  > Choose language</option> 
          <option value="en" > English</option> 
          <option value="ru" > Русский</option> 
          <option value="tj" > Точики</option> 
          </select> 

    </form>
    </td>
```

I know it is not good, but better than nothing.
I will not accept this answer, because it did not solve my problem.